# How to center the text in a table?

Tags: lyx

I'm writing my final lab report and I am trying to fill some information in a table. Problem is, I don't know how to center the text, it looks like it is at the bottom and I want it to be in the middle. I tried to use right-click, and then alignment, but the function seems to be disabled.

[image]

Comment: To the people who gave a downvote: please always give an explanation when you give a downvote. This is FreeZe's first post on tex.se. Although they have experience on other Q&A communities, the conventions on those sites might be different. I'm sorry FreeZe. Please, accept a "welcome" to the tex.se community! I really hope you stick around. Thanks for taking the time to make a screenshot describing what you would like. Could you please also post a minimal example .lyx file? If possible, try to reproduce without a graphic. Please read here: https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: @scottkosty I add my upvote to the n ew contributor FreeZe.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thanks, I appreciate it! I think it's important for us to encourage new members. I actually haven't given a +1 myself, but I will if FreeZe adds a minimal example.

Comment: @scottkosty I'm totally agree with you....:-) my best regads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As starting point:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}% it also load graphicx

    \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
text text
    &   \includegraphics[valign=c, margin=0pt 3pt 0pt 3pt]{example-image-duck}
        &   text   \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

*Note*:
Please always provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` which reproduce your problem. You cannot expect that people, which like to help you will reconstruct code of your image, which seems you already write.